# как cделать отправку значков?

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю бота на discord.py, команду user и хочу сделать типа:

[image]

Что бы бот показал какие есть у пользователя значки, а если их нету то просто писало нету или `None`
Кто знает как это cделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно загрузить свои эмодзи и просто подставлять, а пока только названия

```
@commands.command()
async def user(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    hypesquad_class = str(member.public_flags.all()).replace('[<UserFlags.', '').replace('>]', '').replace('_',' ').replace(':', '').title()
    hypesquad_class = ''.join([i for i in hypesquad_class if not i.isdigit()])
    return await ctx.reply(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{str(member)} User's Badges", description=f"{hypesquad_class}", color=0xff0000), mention_author=False)
```